# React - Component CSS not in order

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to import CSS for each page of my react app but the order of the css import is wrong.

In index.js I load all common css for the site (bootstrap and custom), then go page 'A' that react router handles which also loads its own CSS file. What results is the CSS from page A being loaded before the CSS imports I had in index.js

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Routes from './routes';

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './common.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Routes />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

.

```
//home.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './home.css';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( ... )
  }
}
```

results in:

```
<style home.css />
<style bootstrap.css />
<style common.css />
```

How would I be able to make the CSS from child components load after the parent?